# Bash script add numbers as received in arguments

Tags: linux, bash, sum, arguments

The requirement is that when the script is called as below:

```
my_script.sh 1 2 3 4
```

The script should be able to add these numbers and print sum at the end.

```
num=0
for arg in "$@"
do
  for number in $arg
  do
    (( num += $number ))
  done
done
```

I've written the script as above but not getting the desired output.

Comment: What is the output and how does it differ from the desired output? -- Besides, one the command line, you can use [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) for quick sums, e.g. `echo 1 2 3 4 | tr ' ' '+' | bc`

Comment: The output is just "1 2 3 4".

Comment: I tried to run the  [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/miku/d9dbc4fa5386973d448b2e62d16ed5df/raw/b8a50cfc42e6fb40447caa1c032ca3308fea4914/55092918.sh) with bash and various other shells (zsh, tcsh, mksh) and it works with all of them. You might not invoke the script correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't output anything. Try adding

```
echo $num
```

at the end.

*BUT* your script can be simplified. As written, your script would work for input like

```
my_script.sh 1 '2 3' 4
```

as well, as it first loops over the arguments (`for arg in "$@"`), but then also loops over all the words in each argument (`for number in $arg`). You don't need the second loop.

Also, naming the result `$sum` seems to better explain its purpose. So, you can just type

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for number in "$@" ; do
    (( sum += number ))
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: The output is just "1 2 3 4". It isn't printing the sum.

Comment: It works for me. Are you running the correct script? How do you invoke it? What shell does it use?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I was using an online bash editor. Worked on my local desktop.